cohomological dimension of $G_S$ over unit group for a number field
I imagine the answer is hidden (or in plain sight) somewhere on Neukirch's cohomology book, but given my inability to find it, I thought I should ask to save myself some time.
Let $K$ be a number field and $V_K$, $V=V_{\bar K}$ the group of units of $K$ and  $\bar K$. Fix an (odd) prime $p$ and let $S$ be the primes above $p$, $K_S$ the maximal extension unramified outside of $S$ and $G_S=Gal(K_S/K)$. Write $cd$ for the cohomological dimension. My particular interest would be for $K$ being an imaginary quadratic field but I'd also be curious for any number field $K$.
The questions is: Do we know what is $cd(G_S,V)?$ In particular, do we know whether $H^i(G_S,V)=0$ for all $i\geq 3$?
As an aside question, does the answer to the above differ if we replace $V$ by $E(\bar K)$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $K$?

This problem seems difficult. Let $\mathbb{N}(S)$ be as defined on page 452 of Cohomology of Number Fields. By propositions 8.3.11(iv) and 8.3.18 we obtain $cd_p(G_S,V)\leq 2$. For $p\not \in \mathbb{N}(S)$, my understanding that computing $cd_p(G_S)$ is difficult (see the discussion on page 619), and I don't see a reason that considering just $V$ would make it easier.

@Snacc Thanks for the comment. I am slightly confused with your claim that $cd_p(G_S,V)\leq 2$. this should be for $V_S$, not $V$, right? Is $H^3$ of these two the same?

It should be $V_S=V_{K_S}$, not $V$. $G_S$ does not act on $V$, so I assumed you simply meant $V=V_{K_S}$ instead of $V=V_{\bar{K}}$.

@Snacc By $V$ I do mean by $V_{K_S}$. These are the global units in $K_S$ (i.e the union of the global units $\mathcal O_L^\times$ on the intermediate numberfields). By $V_S$ what I meant are the $S$-units in $K_S$, i.e the union of $\mathcal O_{L,S}^\times$ for $L\subset K_S$. That is different from $V=V_{K_S}$. On Neukirch, he is using the cohomology of the $S$-units

oh of course, my bad. We do still know that $scd_p(G_S)\leq 3$, so it suffices to compute $H^3(G_S,V)$. I wonder if we could use the exact sequence
$$0\to V\to V_S\to J_S\to \langle S\rangle\to 0$$
where $J_S$ is the group of fractional ideals only divisible by primes in $S$, and $\langle S\rangle$ is the subgroup of $\text{Cl}(K)$ generated by primes in $S$.

The exact sequence in my above comment is wrong, the last term shouldn't be $\langle S\rangle$ but something else, not sure what it should be at the moment, but I think it should have trivial $p$-part for $p\in \mathbb{N}(S)$.

All citations are to Cohomology of Number Fields by Neukirch, Schmidt, and Wingberg.
I think what I'm about to say is too big for a comment, but the following is just a single place with the correct version of everything I said in comments, along with an elaboration on some of the ideas. In particular, it is not a complete answer. For a torsion abelian group $A$, denote the $p^\infty$-torsion part by $A(p)$. As I said in my comments, I think computing $H^i(G_S,V)(p)$ is out of reach for primes $p\not \in \mathbb{N}(S)$ (see pg. 452 for the definition of $\mathbb{N}(S)$), so for the rest of this comment I assume $p\in \mathbb{N}(S)$. I also assume $p>2$ or $K$ is totally imaginary.
I claim that $H^i(G_S,V)(p)=0$ for $i>2$. For $i>3$, this follows from the fact that $scd_p(G_S)\leq 3$ (see 8.3.18.) For $i=3$, we have to do a bit more work. Let $V_S$ be the $S$-units. For a number field $L$, let $P_{L,S}$ denote the principal fractional ideals of $L$ only divisible by primes in $S$, and let $$P_S=\varinjlim_{K_S/L/K}P_{L,S}.$$
We have an exact sequence
$$0\to V\to V_S\to P_S\to 0$$
Taking the associated cohomology long exact sequence, we get an exact sequence
$$\cdots\to H^2(G_S,P_S)\to H^3(G_S,V)\to H^3(G_S,V_S)\to \cdots$$
Taking the $p$ parts of these torsion groups and applying 8.3.11, we get
$$\cdots \to H^2(G_S,P_S)(p)\to H^3(G_S,V)(p)\to 0$$
so it suffices to show that $H^2(G_S,P_S)(p)$ vanishes. I claim that $P_S$ is uniquely $p$-divisible, which would imply the result by 1.6.2(c). Since $P_S$ is torsion free, we just need to show that its $p$-divisible. Let $(\alpha)\in P_S$ for $\alpha\in L$, with $L/K$ unramified outside $S$. If we can show $\sqrt[p]{\alpha}\in K_S$, we would obtain the result because $(\sqrt[p]{\alpha})^p=(\alpha)$.
Since $(\alpha)\in P_S$, $\alpha$ is not divisible by primes outside $S$, so therefore $L(\sqrt[p]{\alpha})/L$ is unramified outside primes in $S$ or lying over $p$ by Kummer theory. But $p\in \mathbb{N}(S)$, so $L(\sqrt[p]{\alpha})/L$ is unramified outside $S$, and therefore $\sqrt[p]{\alpha}\in K_S$.

Thanks again for the answer! I think your last exact sequence should be $H^2(G_S,P_S)\to H^3(G_S,V)(p)\to 0$ (as you don't know if the preimage lies in the p part). And if I understand correctly, the above argument shows that $H^2(G_S,P_S)(p)=0$ but not $H^2(G_S,P_S)$ right?

Taking the $p$ part of torsion abelian groups is an exact functor, so we do obtain an exact sequence of the form $H^2(G_S,P_S)(p)\to H^2(G_S,V)(p)\to 0$. To see this consider $f:A\to B(p)$ a map of torsion abelian groups with $f(a)=b$, and suppose $a\in A[n]$. Then let $m$ be such that $m\equiv n\mod \ell^{\nu_{\ell}(n)}$ for $p\neq \ell|n$ and $m\equiv 1\mod p^{\nu_p(n)}$. Then you can check that $f(ma)=b$, and $ma\in A(p)$.

argh, this is too embarassing, you're right! Thanks!
